# Rows empty Error, using GridDB web API to populate data in JSON format

Tags: json, put, webapi, griddb

This question is about sending JSON payloads to a Web API Endpoint.
I am using GridDB's web API to insert data into an existing table, via the PUT call.
I am sending a JSON payload to be inserted into a table(container) as rows.

The HTTP PUT method is sent to a PATH of the form ":cluster/dbs/:database/containers/:container/rows"

( Ref:- [http://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_3/GridDB_Web_API_Reference.html#ロウ登録](http://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_3/GridDB_Web_API_Reference.html#%E3%83%AD%E3%82%A6%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2) )  .

So, My PUT call goes to the prescribed HTTPS URL -  https://cloud1.griddb.com/trialxxxx/griddb/v1/gs_clustertrialxxxx/dbs/test/containers/MyTable/rows

But I get an error :-
{"version":"v2","errorCode":0,"errorMessage":"Rows data is empty"}

Do you see any problem in the JSON payload I am attaching with the PUT request ?
My json file is here - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rkpVPe9FJbRwSgyvv2oG5ms6ZCUijODN6-z_p8886I4/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks
Pratik